# Is there a way to enable a Jetpack module via `functions.php`

Tags: plugin-jetpack

Is there a filter available that would let you specify that a module is active, without you having to use the admin area? I've found filters that let you *hide* modules, but so far nothing for *activating* modules.

Essentially, I want to be able to define it as *always on* so that A) a client can't accidentally disable it, B) it saves me from having to sync DB settings across different environments.

Answer (score 3):

Third party plugins (yeah, including jetpack) are off topic on WPSE, but well, here you go: Jetpack has a filter [`jetpack_get_available_modules`](https://developer.jetpack.com/hooks/jetpack_get_available_modules/), which lets you edit the array of active modules. You can disable a module by unsetting it from the array, or enable it by adding it. Here's how to enable a single module, 'sharedaddy':

```
function wpse248480_filter_jetpack( $modules, $min_version, $max_version ) {
    if (!(in_array('sharedaddy',$modules))) $modules[] = 'sharedaddy';
    return $modules;
    }
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'wpse248480_filter_jetpack', 20, 3 );
```

**UPDATE**

The above only filters the available modules. To actually (de)activate them programmatically use ([source](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/class.jetpack.php#L2478)):

```
function wpse248480_activate_jetpack () {
  Jetpack::activate_module('sharedaddy');
  // Jetpack::deactivate_module('sharedaddy');
  }
add_action('after_setup_theme','wpse248480_activate_jetpack');
```

Comment: No dice I'm afraid; that filters the modules that are *available to be activated,* not the modules that are *actually* activated.

Comment: Can you explain "third party"? Jetpack is not a third party. It is maintained by the Automattic https://github.com/Automattic.

Comment: @prosti WPSE is a gathering place for WP core developers. Anything not in core is considered third party. Jetpack en Woocommerce have their own fora, where you are more likely to find people who know about these particular plugins.

Comment: Nice @cjbj, it is still OK to post a question with `plugin-jetpack` tag and `woocommerce` tag, right. I get the feeling because these tags exist WPSE welcomes these questions. +1 for the "fora" word.

Comment: @prosti There are always border cases between core and plugins. Or you can post the relevant code from the plugin, to make a question on topic here. It's not about your being welcome. It's about the community here being able to help you.

Comment: @cjbj, on main SE, there are many experts in many areas, many gold badges received, so I guess the community in here will grow, and there will be Jetpack and Woocommerce gold badges also. We have such a good answer rate, once commented by Rarst, comparing to the main SE. Leads me to the thought we may give these questions more acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official filter, `jetpack_active_modules`, for this now. It will force enable/disable modules as needed.

Here is an example that will disable everything, and uncommenting a line will enable that module. In your case, you could simply make sure the string describing your desired module is present in the array before returning it.

```
function wpse248480_jetpack_active_modules( $active ) {
    $active = array(
        // 'after-the-deadline',
        // 'carousel',
        // 'comment-likes',
        // 'comments',
        // 'contact-form',
        // 'custom-content-types',
        // 'custom-css',
        // 'enhanced-distribution',
        // 'google-analytics',
        // 'gravatar-hovercards',
        // 'infinite-scroll',
        // 'json-api',
        // 'latex',
        // 'lazy-images',
        // 'likes',
        // 'manage',
        // 'markdown',
        // 'masterbar',
        // 'minileven',
        // 'module-extras',
        // 'module-headings',
        // 'module-info',
        // 'monitor',
        // 'notes',
        // 'photon',
        // 'post-by-email',
        // 'protect',
        // 'publicize',
        // 'pwa',
        // 'related-posts',
        // 'search',
        // 'seo-tools',
        // 'sharedaddy',
        // 'shortcodes',
        // 'shortlinks',
        // 'sitemaps',
        // 'sso',
        // 'stats',
        // 'subscriptions',
        // 'theme-tools',
        // 'tiled-gallery',
        // 'vaultpress',
        // 'verification-tools',
        // 'videopress',
        // 'widget-visibility',
        // 'widgets',
        // 'wordads',
        // 'wpgroho.js',
    );

    return $active;
}

add_filter( 'jetpack_active_modules', 'wpse248480_jetpack_active_modules' );
```